# Communication between app and server over cellular network

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, network-protocols

I'm developing an Android application that communicates with a Rails server. When the application is run on the same network as the Rails server, everything works well (I can access my database on the server). However, when I use the 4g internet on my phone, I can't connect with the server.

My question is, how can I modify my Android app/Rails server so that my Android app can contact my rails server without having to be on the same network?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the server have a public IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not starting the server in development mode. Generally, in development mode the server accepts by default only requests from the same machine (no network connections are accepted).